# Need helping with a sorting error in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

Pandas DF:

[image]

I exported it to excel to be able to see it easier. But basically I am trying to sort it by SeqNo asc and it isnt counting correctly. So instead of going 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2 its going 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,10,10,10,10. Please help out if possible. Here is the code that I have to sort it. I have tried many other methods but it just isnt sorting correctly.

```
 final_df = df.sort_values(by=['SeqNo'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I think it is treating the column values as "String" instead of "int". You can confirm this by checking the datatype of your column (Ex:  use df.info() to check datatype of all the columns in dataframe)

One option to resolve this is to convert that particular column type from string to "int" before sorting and exporting to excel. You can apply pandas "to_numeric()" function before sorting and exporting to excel. Please check pandas documentation for to_numeric() (Refer to https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/change-data-type-columns-pandas-mohit-sharma/ for sample)

Comment: Thanks for confirming, If my answer solved your issue, pls upvote/accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all try Command Given Below for Verifying the type of Data given to you because it's important to understand your data first:-

`print(df.dtypes)`

Above Command will display all the Datatypes of Given Data. Then try to find `SeqNo` **Datatype**. If your Output for `SeqNo` is Showing Something like:-

```
SeqNo    object
dtype: object
```

Then Your Data is of `String` Format and you have to Convert it to **Integer** or **Numeric** Format. So, For Converting it there are two Ways:-

**1. By astype(int) Method**

`df['SeqNo'] = df['SeqNo'].astype(int)`

**2. By to_numeric Method**

`df['SeqNo'] = pd.to_numeric(df['SeqNo'])`

After this Step Try again to Verify the Datatype has been changed or not by typing `print(df.dtypes)` and Now it will show similar output as stated below:-

```
SeqNo    int32
dtype: object
```

**Now you can print Data after Sorting Operation in Ascending Format:-**

`final_df = df.sort_values(by = ['SeqNo'], ascending = True)`